# Styling Custom Meta Boxes?

Tags: css, metabox

I've built a basic meta box and have this in my functions.php.

The current code:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-post-new.php', 'portfolio_admin_style', 11 );
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-post.php', 'portfolio_admin_style', 11 );

function portfolio_admin_style() {
    global $post_type;
    if( 'portfolio' == $post_type )
        wp_enqueue_style( 'portfolio-admin-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/styles/portfolio-admin.css' );
}


add_action('init', 'create_portfolio');
    function create_portfolio() {
        $portfolio_args = array(
            'label' => __('Portfolio'),
            'singular_label' => __('Portfolio'),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
        );
        register_post_type('portfolio',$portfolio_args);
    }

// Input fields
add_action("admin_init", "add_portfolio");
    add_action('save_post', 'update_website_url');
    function add_portfolio(){
        add_meta_box("portfolio_details", "Portfolio Options", "portfolio_options", "portfolio", "normal", "low");
    }
    function portfolio_options(){
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
        $port_excerpt = $custom["port_excerpt"][0];
?>

    <div id="portfolio-options">
        <label>Website URL:</label><input name="website_url" value="<?php echo $website_url; ?>" />
        <label>Excerpt:</label><input name="port_excerpt" value="<?php echo $port_excerpt; ?>" />       
    </div><!--end portfolio-options-->   
<?php
    }
    function update_website_url(){
        global $post;
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "website_url", $_POST["website_url"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "port_excerpt", $_POST["port_excerpt"]);
    }

add_filter("manage_edit-portfolio_columns", "portfolio_edit_columns");
add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "portfolio_columns_display");

function portfolio_edit_columns($portfolio_columns){
    $portfolio_columns = array(
        "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
        "title" => "Project Title",
        "description" => "Description",
    );
    return $portfolio_columns;
}

function portfolio_columns_display($portfolio_columns){
    switch ($portfolio_columns)
    {
        case "description":
            the_excerpt();
            break;              
    }
}
```

The problem is the  stylesheet isn't changing the custom meta box's styling!  I have the stylesheet being called from the correct directory in the code.  If it matters, this is being used with custom post templates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the wp_enqueue_style line from the above code and replace it with this:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-post-new.php', 'portfolio_admin_style', 11 );
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-post.php', 'portfolio_admin_style', 11 );

function portfolio_admin_style() {
    global $post_type;
    if( 'portfolio' == $post_type )
        wp_enqueue_style( 'portfolio-admin-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/portfolio-admin.css' );
}
```

It is better to put the styling for the admin panel in a separate file like in a theme_directory/css/portfolio-admin.css as the front-end styling could conflict with the admin styles.

Comment: I get this... Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback

Comment: Are you sure it is with regard to the above code I suggested? Can I have a look at the code in your template?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Uyqe0070

Comment: Sorry. The called function name was wrong. I have updated the answer. Have a go at the revised answer.

Comment: That fixed the error, but for whatever reason it isn't changing the style of the form at all :-S

Comment: Have you added styles to the theme_directory/css/portfolio-admin.css, as that is the path specified in the function. You need to create that file at that particular path that you specify in the function.

Comment: Does the problem still persist?

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to get back to this, was out celebrating thanksgiving.  Yes, it does.  For whatever reason... I am assuming it isn't pulling the stylesheet correctly.  If I style the elements themselves it works, but that is sloppy so I'd like to do it with your code... it just isn't reading the stylesheet.

Comment: Strange...the same code works on my end.. Could you view the source of your portfolio admin page and check whether the stylesheet is called?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for all the help.  Let me toy with it for a bit and get back to you.

Comment: I've been trying it and quadruple checking everything and it's not working.  I can't figure it out for the life of me.

My functions.php code for all that which is relevant http://pastebin.com/JQEdtHbb

Comment: Alright, your code seems good. Could you view the source of the admin page and tell me whether you can find 'portfolio-admin.css'?

Comment: There's the problem!  Don't know how to fix it though...
It is calling it but the stylesheet link (href=) is calling "/styles/portfolio-admin.css?ver=3.2.1" not "/styles/portfolio-admin.css"

Comment: WordPress by default adds the version to it. Shouldn't make a difference though. If you access the link directly does it show a 404?

Comment: Your code was correct, I had accidentally deleted part of the file name for the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` or `admin_print_styles` action hooks and [`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) like you would on the front end.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to how I'd do this?  I'm having no luck.  Having no luck with: wp_enqueue_style('my_meta_css', MY_THEME_PATH . '/style.css');.. I'll post my entire code above.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, I'm not sure there's a `$post_type` global but pretty sure there is a `$post->post_type` so you should probably be comparing to that. Secondly, unless you want your child themes to completely override all your CSS files (i.e. not use them even if not overriden) then you should be using `get_template_directory_uri()` instead of stylesheet directory.

Then, to make sure your stylesheet is included, view the source of the add new portfolio item page and see if your stylesheet is there and that the link is not broken, i.e. it links to the correct CSS file.

Finally, make sure the rules in your stylesheet are not the problem (as @ptriek mentioned above), add a `#portfolio-options label { color: red !important; }` and remove everything else from the stylesheet, this should turn your portfolio option labels to red. If it works then your stylesheet is fine and the rest is up to its contents :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If this does not change the css style on your custom meta box, the problem is most likely with your css.

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'portfolio_admin_style');

function portfolio_admin_style($hook) {
    global $page_handle;
    if ( ($hook == 'post.php') || ($hook == 'post-new.php') || ($hook == 'page.php') || ($hook == 'page-new.php') || ($_GET['page'] == $page_handle) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'portfolio-admin-style', (get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/portfolio-admin.css'), false, '1.0.0' );
    }
}
```